Qual a função do operador de acesso ao índice ^ em C#?
Um dos syntactic sugars do C# é o Implicit index access ou operador de acesso implícito ao índice ^.
O que é exatamente esse syntactic sugar e o que ele faz?
Exemplo:
int[] num = { 10, 20, 30 };

var x = num[^1];
if (num[^2] == 0)
{
    ...
}


Conforme a documentação, o operador ^ indica a posição do elemento a partir do final de uma sequência, por exemplo, ^1 aponta para o último elemento de uma sequência e ^length aponta para o primeiro elemento de uma sequência. Este recurso está disponivel desde a versão 8.0 do C#.
Então seguindo o exemplo:
int[] num = { 10, 20, 30 };
Console.WriteLine(num[^3]); // 10
Console.WriteLine(num[^2]); // 20
Console.WriteLine(num[^1]); // 30

O [^1] iria obter o 30, [^2] iria obter o 20 e [^3] iria obter o 10 da num.
Os operadores de índice e intervalo podem ser usados com tipos que são contáveis, esses tipos tem uma propriedade int chamada Count ou Length com um get acessível.

Nota: Expressões de coleção também dependem de tipos contáveis.

Você também pode definir uma variável como Index (System.Index), por exemplo:
int[] foo = [2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025];
Index bar = ^1;
Console.WriteLine(foo[bar]); // retorna: 2025

Você também pode usar o Count ou o Length com o ^, por exemplo, para obter o primeiro item você poderia usar ^num.Length, algo como:
Console.WriteLine(foo[^foo.Length]); // 2019


Nota: No que foi citado antes, como sendo a expressão ^e o resultado de e deve ser implicitamente conversível para int, o que permite usar o ^.

Operador Range (..)
O operador .. (System.Range), também disponivel desde a versão 8.0 do C#, especifica o início e o fim de um intervalo de índices como seus operandos. O operando à esquerda é um início inclusivo de um intervalo. O operando à direita é um fim exclusivo de um intervalo, conforme a documentação:
public Range (Index start, Index end);




Parametro
Descrição




Index start
O índice inicial inclusivo do intervalo.


Index end
O índice final exclusivo do intervalo.




Nota: Na expressão a..b, os resultados de a e b devem ser implicitamente conversíveis para Int32 (System.Int32) ou Index (System.Index).

Então podemos usar o Range com Index, o que também permite o ^, exemplo:
int[] foo = [2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025];
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", foo[1..3]));  // 2020 2021
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", foo[0..^0])); // 2019 2020 2021 2022 2023 2024 2025
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", foo[0..^1])); // 2019 2020 2021 2022 2023 2024
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", foo[1..^1])); // 2020 2021 2022 2023 2024

// Veja as próximas explicações abaixo
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", foo[^6..]));   // 2020 2021 2022 2023 2024 2025
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", foo[^6..^3])); // 2020 2021 2022

Conforme o exemplo o 0..^1 aparou removendo o final, enquanto o 0..^0 trouxe tudo.
Note que expressões com 0 e ^0 podem ser simplificadas nas expressões com o operador .., pois:

a.. é equivalente ao a..^0
..b é equivalente ao 0..b
.. é equivalente ao 0..^0




Expressão
Descrição




..
Obtêm os valores na coleção


..end
Obtêm os valores do início até o end exclusivamente.


start..
Obtêm os valores do start inclusivamente até o final.


start..end
Obtêm os valores de start inclusivamente até end exclusivamente.


^start..
Obtêm os valores do start inclusivamente até o final, contando a partir do final.


..^end
Obtêm os valores do início até o end exclusivamente contando a partir do final.


start..^end
Obtêm os valores de start inclusivamente até end exclusivamente contando a partir do final.


^start..^end
Obtêm os valores de start inclusive até end exclusivamente, contando ambos a partir do final.




muito bom, isso me fez lembrar um pouco o seletor nth do CSS :)

Não sei se entendi direito, mas me pareceu que o ^e é o mesmo que fazer foo[-e] em Python, onde ele conta de trás para frente as posições
